# MMDrawerController with UITabBarController showing a black gap on top of the center view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, mmdrawercontroller

I am opening a UITabBarController with [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) on the left side.
So from my delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` I am making a MMDrawerController with centerNav is a `TabBarController`  and leftNav is a ViewController with Navigation controller. So as expected the tabbar is coming with the `mmdrawer` but there is a black gap on top of the `LandingTabBarController`.If I open the LandingTabBarController directly then it is coming from the top. Whats going wrong?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LandingTabBarController *landingTabBarController = [[LandingTabBarController alloc]initWithManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    UIViewController * drawerNavController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DrawerViewController"];

    UINavigationController *centerNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:landingTabBarController];

    UINavigationController *leftNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:drawerNavController];


    centerNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    leftNav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    _drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:centerNav leftDrawerViewController:leftNav];

    _drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
    _drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView;
    _drawerController.showsShadow = NO;
    //[_drawerController setDrawerVisualStateBlock:[MMDrawerVisualState slideVisualStateBlock]];
    [_drawerController setDrawerVisualStateBlock:MMDrawerSideNone];
    self.window.rootViewController = _drawerController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

### This is my LandingTabBarController viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIViewController *firstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [firstViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [secondViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [tabViewControllers addObject:firstViewController];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:secondViewController];
    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];

    firstViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"one" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_feed"] tag:1];
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"two" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_apps"] tag:2]; 
}
```

[image]

### Screenshot of the debugger

[image]

Comment: look into the view debugger, and see if the red view is a separate view or not!!! I think red view is separate view adding to the tab bar window!!

Comment: I just added a UIviewController with red background color  into the tabbarcontroller

Comment: can u post the screenshot of the view debugger ?

Comment: edited with screenshot

Comment: i meant the view debugger!!! Google for view debugger in xcode

Comment: Btw problem is sorted out. I was creating a UITabbarController and in viewDidLoad I was adding the firstviewcontroller and secondviewcontroller.Maybe that was the problem. Now I am creating a tabbarcontroller and setting it as the certernav in my delegate before setting the root view

Comment: I will read about the view debugger . Thanks